# How to open a webpage located on a server that has another network in my laptop

Tags: web, networking, server, proxy, remote-desktop

I'm working on my laptop on my company network, when I want to open this specific webpage I should go Remote Desktop to the Server then open this Webpage.

Note the server working on another Network and need login access.

so I ask if I can make shortcut or away to access to this webpage from my laptop without entering remote desktop.

Answer (score 0):

For example If the server ip is 10.10.12.12 I should first go there via RD and entering the access credentials user name and pass then after login I access the webpage there. Now I need to open this ewbpage without RD